# Referencing the Component of a vector

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, vector, vector-calculus, reference-request

If I were to define a vector

```
r = {2, 0} + t*({5, 4} - {2, 0})
>>{2 + 3 t, 4 t}
Sqrt[(D[r[1]])^2 + (D[r[2]])^2]
```

How do I properly reference a single component of the vector so that I can use it for something else like derive. This is for program to solve line integrals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Sqrt[(D[r[1]])^2 + (D[r[2]])^2]

You can't just write `D[somthing]` you need to write `D[something, variable]`.

You can try

```
r = {2, 0} + t*({5, 4} - {2, 0});
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Sqrt[ D[ r[[1]], t]^2 + D[ r[[2]], t]^2]
(*5*)
```

If it makes it easier, you could give the components names, and just use the names

```
x = r[[1]];
y = r[[2]];

Sqrt[ D[x,t]^2 + D[y,t]^2 ]
(*5*)
```

Or You could also write

```
Norm@Grad[r, {t}] 
(*5*)
```

which gives same result if I am following what you are trying to do right.